# Не работает изменение цвета ProgressBar после перехода проекта с Delphi 6 на Delphi 10.2

Tags: delphi

Вот этот известный способ работал у меня на Borland Delphi 6:

```
MyProgressBar.Brush.Color := clWindow;
tmpColor := clGreen;
SendMessage(MyProgressBar.Handle, PBM_SETBARCOLOR, 0, tmpColor);
tmpColor := clRed;
SendMessage(MyProgressBar.Handle, PBM_SETBARCOLOR, 0, tmpColor);
```

После конвертации проекта на последнюю версию Embarcadero Delphi 10.2 этот же самый код никаких изменений не вызывает. Фон остается по-прежнему серый, а цвет полосы прогресса один раз рисуется зеленым, все следующие действия SendMessage цвета на красный не меняют.

Пробовал также параметры: BackgroundColor, BarColor - не помогают.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если включены темы оформления, подобный подход невозможен. Подробнее у [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Вы можете отключить темы (Project > Options > Application. Снять галочку с опции "Enable Runtime Themes"), только убедитесь, что:

1. вы выставляете данную опцию для всех конфигураций или хотя бы для
   той конфигурации, в которой будете тестировать проект (В опциях
   сверху есть выпадающий ComboBox, где вы выбираете Debug/Release/All)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. включен стиль по умолчанию (Windows) - в меню Project > Options >
   Application/Appearance

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда всё заработает. Но также заработает и обычное присваивание цвета свойствам `TProgressBar`, например:

```
MyProgressBar.BackgroundColor := clRed;
MyProgressBar.BarColor := clYellow;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я попробовал, галочку снял, сохранил изменения, но ничего не изменилось - при открытии окна галочка снова вернулась. В чем тут дело?

Comment: Цвет ProgressBar тоже меняться не стал

Comment: @AVM Дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь все заработало!

Comment: @AVM Если ответ является решением, отметьте его галочкой. Здесь так заведено.

Comment: Спасибо, отметил.